# Use variables defined in result-count.php template elsewhere in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, product

I want to build my own result count system on my page (ideally from the theme function file).

I am trying to use the variables used in the template `result-count.php` itself, which include `$total`, `$per_page`, `$current`, `$first` and `$last`. But I am getting error **undefined variable**.

I have looked for a function that would get me those in an array but the only function I am finding is `woocommerce_result_count()` which is no use as it only includes the result-count.php template.

Any ideas?

Edit:
Wrapped function following answer from Loic:

```
 function get_product_listing_count()
{

    global $wp_query;

            // Define each variable again (before using it)
            $paged    = max( 1, $wp_query->get( 'paged' ) );
            $per_page = $wp_query->get( 'posts_per_page' );
            $total    = $wp_query->found_posts;

            $result= '';
            if ( $total <= $per_page || -1 === $per_page ) {
                if ($total == 1){$result = "Showing all $total results";}else{$result = "Showing 1 result";}
            } 
            else 
            {
                $first    = ( $per_page * $paged ) - $per_page + 1;
                $last     = min( $total, $wp_query->get( 'posts_per_page' ) * $paged );
                $result = "Showing  $first &ndash; $last of $total results";
            }


return $result;
}//end function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use the variable somewhere else you need first the following before in your php:

```
// call $wp_query global variable once (if not included)
global $wp_query;

// Define each variable again (before using it)
$paged    = max( 1, $wp_query->get( 'paged' ) );
$per_page = $wp_query->get( 'posts_per_page' );
$total    = $wp_query->found_posts;
$first    = ( $per_page * $paged ) - $per_page + 1;
$last     = min( $total, $wp_query->get( 'posts_per_page' ) * $paged );
```

But this need to stay (to be) in the query loop.

Comment: Thank you, very useful. If it can help someone here it is wrapped in a function used in my functions theme: